# Will static homepage load faster in wordpress than postpage as a homepage?

Tags: performance, wordpress

I would like to create a static homepage that sits out of wordpress framework which would have links to the actual wordpress posts. I think that the homepage would load much faster that the homepage as a part of wordpress. Is it possible or do I still need to create the static homepage within wordpress framework as .html page?

Comment: To extend your logic, you can make every page a static HTML page. That would load faster than Wordpress. In that case, why even bother with Wordpress then?

Comment: No. The rest of the content will be dynamic made. Like search, leave comments, feeds..etc. As I am no php or other back-end language experienced I chose wordpress. All I want is the homepage to pop up immediately so it doesn't have to wait until all the scripts are loaded as what's happening with regular wordpress homepage.

Comment: Everybody wants their pages to load faster. Your suggested solution will work, but sounds like an odd workaround. You'll have to manually update this page. And it will only work for people who go to the homepage; search engine visitors often go to internal pages and skip the homepage entirely.

Comment: Its not a suggestion. Just a question. I am trying to find out if it is possible. The homepage will have enough info about the subject that the homepage itself will be attractive enough for search engines. Consider the fact that Google looks at upload time.

Comment: I swear I'm not trying to be argumentative. But your logic extends to Wordpress in general. I don't know why you are singling out the homepage here. If Google looks at site speed, and Wordpress is slow loading, then why use it at all? Keep in mind I don't know your site at all.

Comment: I did explain that above why wordpress. And there is no other alternative for me. Or is it? (Read my first comment to your answer).

Answer (score 1):

Well what you can actually do is cache the wordpress pages so it would perform as a static page, check the caching plugins on http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Optimization/Caching

Comment: Thank you. I will definitely check that out!

Comment: WP Super Cache will "preload" cache pages, so you can prepare static HTML versions of your pages before anyone visits them.